# Jobs en Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5

Estoy utilizando Jobs en Laravel, el cual implemento queues con redis.

Al enviar un formulario llamo a la función:

```
private function allUsersNotifications($title, $description) {
    $users = $this->userRepo->search();

    dispatch(new NotificationsAllUsers($users, $title, $description));      
}
```

y dentro del Job (NotificationsAllUsers) hago:

```
    class NotificationsAllUsers implements ShouldQueue {

    use InteractsWithQueue,
        Queueable,
        SerializesModels;

    public $users;
    public $title;
    public $description;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($users, $title, $description) {
        $this->users = $users;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->description = $description;  
        Log::info(3);
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle() {
        Log::info(4);
    }

}
```

Al correr el job, el log me imprime bien, pero si dentro del metodo handle eliminio Log::info(4) y quiero imprimir otra cosa, como Log::info(1), me sigue imprimiendo el 4. Ya es la segunda vez que me pasa que modifico algo del handle de un job y como que no toma el cambio, como que queda en cache.

Elimino el cache de redis y de los queues y sigue igual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la documentación dice:

> Remember, queue workers are long-lived processes and store the booted application state in memory. As a result, they will not notice changes in your code base after they have been started. So, during your deployment process, be sure to restart your queue workers.

Por lo tanto vas a tener que tirar:

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

Ya es medio tarde la respuesta pero quizás sirva para otro.